# Does Asp.net zero automatically log errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net zero framework. I have seen that there is an audit log but no error logging. Is there a set up to enable error logging automatically or should we implement the error logging separately?

Comment: Try contacting support of aspnetzero https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions

Answer (score 0):

error logging is automatically supported, just look on APP_DATA folder on the Host project, also AuditLogs register all logs if you don't filter it.